# PyCurl - strings are not supported for this option

Tags: python

why this returns `ERROR: strings are not supported for this option`
Also tried to call just simply IP and Port as strings, not working.

```
import pycurl

proxy = '10.10.10.10:00000'
splitProxy = proxy.split(':')

try:
    c1 = pycurl.Curl()
    c1.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://www.google.com')
    c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, splitProxy[0])
    c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, splitProxy[1])
    c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)    

    c1.perform()

except Exception, detail:
        print "ERROR:", detail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port should be an integer, you need to convert your string to integer like this:

```
c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, int(splitProxy[1]))
```

You can also put your port number directly like below:

```
c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 5000)  # If port is 5000
```

Your code should looks like this:

```
import pycurl

proxy = '10.10.10.10:8080'  # You need some valid port number!
splitProxy = proxy.split(':')

try:
    c1 = pycurl.Curl()
    c1.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://www.google.com')
    c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, splitProxy[0])
    c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, int(splitProxy[1]))
    c1.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)    

    c1.perform()

except Exception, detail:
        print "ERROR:", detail
```

Comment: ERROR: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: @Shartigan What about `int(float(splitProxy[1]))`? also your port should be something like `3000`, `5000`, not `00000`

Comment: Still invalid literal :/

Comment: What is your port please? it should be an integer like 5000 not 00000

Comment: At last try was 0808, but crashes at the ip, exactly: ERROR: invalid literal for float(): 192.168.1.1

Comment: You want to say 8080? 0880 is 880

Comment: Do not convert your ip, just the port needs to be converted

Comment: Not necessary what I use mate, the problem isn`t with handling the script, is with handling the string. Also tried to convert unicode format, but of course not working.

Comment: Try with the code I posted now, but please replace 8080 with you real port not something like 00000